# ¿Colores de datos X en Barchart?

Tags: java, android-studio

Cómo mostrar la descripcion de los datos al lado de los colores que se marcan en la imagen de abajo?
Librería: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mira este artículo, creo que te servirá: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend

Comment: Gracias por su intento pero no puedo resolver :(